# How to assaign leads to users in Multiple queues through round robin with trigger in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-communities

In my org there are three queues (names are Digital,Btl,Atl) containing three users. In my lead object there is a picklist field(having same queue values).
when lead inserted with pick list value as 'Digital', owner of inserting lead should be update as user in Digital queue(user should get selected in round robin fashion inside queue). How can i achieve that through Trigger...PLZ HELP ME OUT..

Answer (score 1):

A rough overview:

- Create "Next In Queue" `boolean` field for your users, `false` default.
- Choose who starts and set to `true`.
- In before trigger, query for next in queue user of related queue.
- Change owner to that user.
- Update user's "Next in Queue" to `false`.
- Set the next user in the queue to `true`.

Depending on your code you can do much better than this, but I hope this gets you started!